# Is there a way to make Dafny generate C# code without also compiling the code to a .dll or .exe?

Tags: dafny

The following options seems relevant but the result is no .dll/.exe and no .cs:

/compile:0 /compileTarget:cs

There doesn't seem to be any other command line options to control this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:

/compile:0 /compileTarget:cs /spillTargetCode:2

Comment: There will be a better way to solve this problem soon, i.e. https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/issues/2036
By the way, would you be ok with Dafny generating not only the source, but also the associated csproj with it?

Comment: @MikaëlMayer I would prefer to just generate the source. My use case is generating verified C# code that I can include in a legacy non-verified C# code base. It is a great way to step-by-step introducing verified code into a "traditional" project.